# Redirecting to the same page results in blank page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jstl

I am creating a `java` servlet web applicaiton where I take user input at `index.jsp` and shows result at `result.jsp` page upon `POST` action. Before submiting the form I validate user input. If any validation error is found than I want to `redirect` user to the same `index.jsp` page with the error messages. But the `redirect` action results in a blank page. Here is what I have done so far -

Servlet class `doPost` method -

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String name = req.getParameter("name");

    //this is just a dto class
    CovidQa covidQa = new CovidQa(name);

    CovidTestValidator validator = new CovidTestValidator();
    boolean hasError = validator.validate(covidQa, req);

    if (hasError) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }

    req.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

Validator's `validate` method-

```
public boolean validate(CovidQa covidQa, HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean hasError = false;

    if (covidQa.getName() == null || covidQa.getName().equals("")) {
        request.setAttribute("nameErr", "Name can not be null");
        hasError = true;
    }

    return hasError;
}
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Covid-19</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>CovidTest</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Covid-19</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Cov</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

`index.jsp` -

```
<form action="Cov" method="post">
    //input fields
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text"
           id="name"
           name="name">
    <span>${nameErr}</span>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: 1) You're not redirecting at all. You're forwarding. 2) When there's an error, you're forwarding to index.jsp and then to result.jsp. Clearly the system got confused. Shouldn't you logically put the forward to result.jsp in an else block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.getRequestDispatcher()` doesn't `return` from the method implicitly. If you don't mention `return` explicitly, immediate lines also will be executed by the compiler.
As @BalusC commented *the system got confused* by executing two `req.getRequestDispatcher()` statement consecutively.

Either you need to `return` explicitly -

```
if (hasError) {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    return;
}

req.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Or, put the later one inside `else` block -

```
if (hasError) {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
} else {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```